# Centering an image link with HTML and no CSS

Tags: html

I am trying to center an image using only HTML and no CSS, is this possible? I have tried the following code:

```
<a href="link">
<img src="URL" align="center"></a>
```

However the image doesn't move. How can I solve this?

The image I am trying to center is the donate button on the right column of our [blog](https://wewanttolearn.wordpress.com/) I am placing the link in a "text" widget so the CSS doesn't seem to work there.

Comment: You can't even use in-line css?

Comment: Just why the hatred with CSS?

Comment: @hjpotter92 I tried to use CSS but it is in a "text" widget of wordpress.com so it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: The `align` attribute has been depreciated in favor of CSS style sheets. That being said, try setting CSS `text-align:center` on the href around your image rather than the image itself.

Comment: @showdev Good idea, I've updated my answer to reflect this

Comment: Some routers strip CSS when they don't trust a webpage or an e-mail sender.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well, you *could* use `<center>`, but it is no longer supported. Your best bet here is to use the style attribute in HTML and `text-align:center`. This won't directly center the image, so you would wrap it in a div with the styling:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
<a href="link">

<img src="URL" align="center"></a>
</div>
```

After looking at a comment that was posted, I see that you actually don't need the div. Just apply it to the link around it.

```
<a href="link" style="text-align: center">

<img src="URL" align="center"></a>
```

There is no possible way to do this without CSS, unless you want to use outdated stuff.

Comment: So the answer is, no, it is not possible to do without CSS.

Comment: Leng... I tested the following in Chrome and Opera and they worked fine.

<center></center>
<p align="middle"></p>

Answer (score 6):

Another way that doesn't use CSS is to wrap the image in a `table`. While it's not the best way to do things on the Internet as it stands, but it is compliant with older e-mail clients, browsers, and systems where companies strip CSS from contents on a firewall.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" width="100%">
<tr><td align="center">
<img src="URL">
</td></tr>
</table>
```

While I realize this question was about implementation in WordPress, Google thought it was relevant to my own issue.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily align image without CSS
Just wrap your image in a div tag and use align='center'
For example:

```
<div align='center'>
   <img src="Capture.JPG" alt="logo header"><br/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can align the image to center by

`<p style="text-align:center;"><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo"></p>`

Answer (score 1):

For anyone experiencing this issue with Markdown in a Read-the-Docs website, only the `<center>` option works!

Answer (score 0):

I would just place some p tags around it

```
<p align="center" ><a href "link"> <img src="link"></a></p>
```